# How to pass parameters to a controller (testing)

Tags: php, codeigniter, testing, phpunit

I'm testing with PHPUnit a controller which has at least one parameter:

```
public function testSomething($a,$b='')
{
}
```

Im trying to test it this way:

```
$params = array('a'=>'foo','b'=>'bar');
$output = $this->request('POST', ['MyController','Something'], $params);
```

But I'm getting:

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MyController::Something

How can I pass those parameters?

Note: I used a library for integrating PHPUnit to Codeigniter:

```
"require-dev": {
        "kenjis/ci-phpunit-test": "^0.15.0"
    }
```

Comment: What version of codeigniter?

Comment: Have you tried this :$output = $this->request('POST', ['MyController','testSomething'], $params);

Comment: V3x, and yes its the same i posted rigt?

Comment: from where you are passing these

Comment: application/test/controllers/Payment_test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use flash_ which is in the CodeIgniter.Try the below one:

```
$params = array('a'=>'foo','b'=>'bar');
$this->session->set_flashdata('params ', $params);
$output = $this->request('POST', ['MyController','Something']);
```

Controller:

In Controller you can get the values from flashdata function.

```
$this->session->flashdata('params');
```

or

```
$a='foo';$b='bar';
$output = $this->request('POST', ['MyController','Something',$a,$b]);
```

Comment: It's an api and it's been already used, so I'd like to maintain it's specification

Comment: so you are trying to pass in request only?

Comment: yep, I don't know if there is any other way, but I'd like to call it in the exact same way the apps using the api use it

Comment: Then you can try like this: `$this->request('POST', ['MyController','Something', $params]);`

Comment: almost, the way to go is `$this->request('POST', ['MyController','Something',$param1,$param2....]);` and it works :-) Please, edit (and thanks!)

Comment: Severity:    Warning
Message:     urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
You can't pass an array, you need to pass arg1,arg2,..

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$params = array(
            'a' => 'foo',
            'b' => 'bar'
        );
$output = $this->request('GET', 'my_controller/my_function', $params);
```